# Can a category be an object of itself?

Tags: logic, category-theory

Looking into Category Theory, and I can't get away with plugging Russell's paradox into the category of all categories. I will make the argument as following:

For the category of all categories $\mathbf{Cat}$, it must contain itself as an object. Therefore, we can define following:

an **ordinary** category of categories is one without itself being its own object, and

an **extraordinary** category of categories is one with itself being its own object.

Then for the category of all ordinary categories, would this category contain itself? The same illustration goes as Russell's paradox to demonstrate a contradiction.

However, I don't get in which way this construction can be denied. In which construct that i am missing to help  Category Theory to get away with this paradox?

Comment: How do you know there exists a category of all ordinary categories?

Comment: @Rahul I don't know. but I as well don't know if $\mathbf{Cat}$ exists.

Comment: @Rahul ok, I will try to argue category of all ordinary categories exists. obviously, in this category, morphisms are functors, and since it's a subcategory of $\mathbf{Cat}$, we know the composition of morphisms, i.e. functors, exist and is associative. also, there exists one identity functor for each category object in this category. hence it forms a category.

Comment: It is meaningless, from the category-theoretic point of view, to ask whether a category contains itself as an object (in a strictly set-theoretic sense), because this condition is not invariant under equivalence (or even isomorphism) of categories.

Comment: Separately, there is no (locally small) category of all categories, because the collection of functors between two categories need not form a set. There is a (locally small) category of small categories, and there's no contradiction there.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan could you elaborate. in which sense it's variant?

Comment: This is a wonderful question, and/but @QiaochuYuan's objection (that the question is not parse-able/sensible in category-theoretic terms) shows, to my mind, that category theory (in a naive sense) does indeed dodge the Russell-et-al antimonies that plagued naive set theory. Worth thinking about, for sure...

Comment: There is no category of _all_ categories. You can define a category $\mathbf{Cat}$ of all _small_ categories (relatively to some universe in some fondational theory), but then $\mathbf{Cat}$ is not itself small. Depending on your fondations, $\mathbf{Cat}$ can eventually be considered small for a bigger universe, but in any case $\mathbf{Cat}$ is not an object of $\mathbf{Cat}$.

Comment: @Pece could you elaborate which part is missing to deny the existence of category of all categories? honestly I just get myself started so I don't see lots of arguments straightforward.